# Setting ranges using named sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Having a freeze. I am trying to set a publicly declared range (`dataIrradianceRange` and `dataTempRange`), but keep getting the method range of object failed error.  Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

```
Public Sub getData()

'for each loop in data book to find right columns for sites
'each site has two columns in the data book...irradiance and amb temp
For j = 2 To siteCount * 2 Step 2
    If dataSheet.Cells(1, j).Value = siteNameArray(i) Then

        Set dataIrradianceRange = dataSheet.Range(Cells(5, j), Cells(lastRow, j)) 
        Set dataTempRange = dataSheet.Range(Cells(5, j + 1), Cells(lastRow, j + 1)) 
        Exit For
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with full range qualification

```
    With dataSheet
        Set dataIrradianceRange = .Range(.Cells(5, j), .Cells(lastRow, j)) 
        Set dataTempRange = .Range(.Cells(5, j + 1), .Cells(lastRow, j + 1)
    End With
```

Comment: So this works, but I don't understand why it does over what I tried.  Would you be able to explain it?

Comment: a `Range` reference without an explicit worksheet qualification would implicitly assume it as the _active_ one so that in `dataSheet.Range(Cells(5, j), Cells(lastRow, j)) `, while its `datasheet.Range(` part would refer to a range in the worksheet that `datasheet` was previously set to, the `Cells(5, j), Cells(lastRow, j)` part would point to a range in the _active_ worksheet, which could not be the same as `datasheet`. Inside a `With datasheet - End With` block all range references beginning with a dot (`.`) would implicitly assume `datasheet` as their parent object